# Close/Kill "Services" app from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, kill-process

I'm trying to kill the "Service" app (if it is open) from Powershell.

This does not work:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Services" /T
```

This does work, but it kills all the "mmc.exe":

```
taskkill /IM mmc.exe
```

Any idea how I can kill just the service app (`service.msc`)?

Comment: `taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Services"` _should_ work, and does on my W11 22H2 machine. What is your environment?

Answer (score 1):

process objects have a window title property you can use. Try something like this:

```sh
# view running processes
Get-Process 'mmc' | select id,name,MainWindowTitle

   Id Name MainWindowTitle
   -- ---- ---------------
18452 mmc  Services       
24828 mmc  Disk Management

# close only the services app
Get-Process 'mmc' | Where MainWindowTitle -eq 'Services' | Stop-Process

# verify other mmc processes did not stop:
Get-Process 'mmc' | select id,name,MainWindowTitle

   Id Name MainWindowTitle
   -- ---- ---------------
24828 mmc  Disk Management
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this command and it works:

```
tasklist | findstr mmc.exe
TASKKILL /F /PID ID
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the OP's own attempt, so a different approach shouldn't be necessary. Aside from that, your solution leaves out  a step that is crucial for a _programmatic_ solution, namely how to extract the PID from the output of  `tasklist | findstr mmc.exe`